# Tableau calculate with total amount

Tags: tableau-api

I want to calculate with a total sum of all values and divide this of attribute level.

In the picture below you can see my problem:

[image]

I want to calculate the RAMT amount for each RSAL number divide by the sum of all RREM (660,687). The problem is, if I generate a calculated field with the code `SUM([Ramt])/Sum([Rrem])*100` Tableau calculate with the Rrem amount for each RSAL number.

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this using [level of detail calculations](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.html).
To get the denominator, try something like this:

`{Exclude [attributename]:sum(RREM)}`

Comment: Hi Deano, thank you very much for your answer. It solved my problem.